# how to hide message of asking user to allow to access your location in core location frameworks?

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-location

i want to access user location using core location frameworks but don't show message to user that "allow to access your location" which ask at staring of application.

is there any way to hide this messge of core location frameworks.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be a serious user privacy concern, so the answer is **no**.

How would you feel if all of a sudden an app can see where you are without you knowing it?

Comment: we have to develop application for transport company. they want to monitor their vehicles root and distance they travel. but they don't want their driver know they monitor them.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option here is to report on drivers that refuse permission. After that enforcement is an Management and Human Resources problem.
If the phones are provide to the drivers by the company, then you could consider allowing the location to be used when configuring the phone, and then locking down the phone setting so it cannot be revoked.

A creative problem solver will of course find other ways to defeat being tracked through their phone - putting it in a metal tin would work pretty well :)